# selenium - jUnit4

Tags: selenium, junit4, selenium-ide

I am trying to run the below code but in vain.

Code is not compiling and giving error as "**selenium cannot be resolved**".
Can anyone look into the below code  -

```
package com.example.tests;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class prashantk {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://book.theautomatedtester.co.uk/");
        selenium.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAuto_1() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/chapter2");
        verifyEquals("Button with name", selenium.getValue("name=but2"));
        verifyEquals("chocolate", selenium.getValue("xpath=(//input[@name='verifybutton'])[2]"));
        selenium.click("link=Index");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("60000");
        verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Chapter4"));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have references to a field named `selenium`, but there is no such field defined.

Somewhere in your class, probably on a line just before the `@Before`, you want to add this field:

```
Selenium selenium;
```

Apparently from comments you also don't have the methods `verifyEquals` and `verifyTrue` referenced in your code.  Those methods are defined in a base class `SeleneseTestCase` which your test should extend:

```
public class prashantk extends SeleneseTestCase {
```

Comment: Thanks Don this is working. But another issue cropped up where I've used "verifyEuals" and "verifyTrue". For "verifyEuals" it is giving error as - The method verifyEquals(String,string) is undefined for the type prashantk. And for "verifyTrue" it is giving error as - The method verifyTrue(boolean) is undefined for prashantk.

Comment: Can you post the entire stacktrace here, so that we can have a better idea about your problem. Also show us the code if it was updated after the above posted selenium code. That would be helpful.

Comment: @HemChe:  There's probably no stacktrace, as it's a compile error rather than runtime.

Comment: I've found a solution somehow.

Comment: I've found a solution somehow. I used - import org.junit.Assert.*; and used "assertEquals" instead of "verifyEuals".Thanks Don and Hem for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below line in your code as shown below

selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://book.theautomatedtester.co.uk/");

```
             to
```

DefaultSelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://book.theautomatedtester.co.uk/");

Comment: I've found a solution somehow. I used - import org.junit.Assert.*;  and used "assertEquals" instead of "verifyEuals".Thanks Don and Hem for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at code gives an impression it was done in Selenium IDE first the exported to a tool like eclipse.
I really don't think 'verifyEquals' exist in WebDriver instead use JUnit assertions or Hamcrest assertions. Try to write your code from scratch in Java its a lot less hassle.